# AngularJS reusing the same controller on one page, with different configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to display two elements on a page controlled by **different instances of the same controller**, *but* I need to register some external information that will be unique (one "joystick" gets an identifying property set, like "player = one" while the other gets "player = two").I'm not sure of the best way of pulling this off exactly

Here's a generic example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<!-- These need to have different configurations -->
<div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
     ng-controller="JoystickCtrl">...</div>

<div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
     ng-controller="JoystickCtrl">...</div>
```

Should I:

**Use a directive?**

```
<div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
     ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" player="one">...</div>
<div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
     ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" player="two">...</div>
```

**Use $injector?** (fyi - this might be an incorrect implementation)

```
<div ng-controller="DualJoyCtrl">
    <div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
         ng-controller="joyOne" player="one">...</div>
    <div ng-include src="'joystick/joy.tpl.html'" 
         ng-controller="joyTwo" player="two">...</div>
</div>

-----

.controller('DualJoyCtrl', function ($injector, JoystickCtrl, $scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.joyOne = $injector.instantiate(JoystickCtrl, {$scope: $rootScope.$new(), player:"one"});
   $scope.joyTwo = $injector.instantiate(JoystickCtrl, {$scope: $rootScope.$new(), player:"two"});
});
```

**Or... not do this?**

I realize this is similar to another, seemingly inconclusive stack post:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Since ngController is initialized before ngInit, in order to have data available in controller at once, you should wrap ngController in parent element with ngInit:

```
<div ng-init="player = 'one'">
   <div ng-controller="JoystickCtrl">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**Original answer**

I think simple ng-init would suffice:

```
<div ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" ng-init="player='one'">...</div>
<div ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" ng-init="player='two'">...</div>
```

Comment: or create a directive itself

Comment: I'd like to add that the $scope.player property is NOT immediately available to the controller, but it is available in the template.  If you ```console.log($scope.player)``` from within the controller you will get undefined unless it's about 50ms or later after controller initialization.

Answer (score 3):

Store your config values in a data attribute, and retrieve it within the controller using `$attrs.`  (The [AngularJS ngInit documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) recommends to say clear of `ng-init` unless *aliasing special properties of ngRepeat*. ) A similar answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612752/88204). This code snippet gives you the general idea:

**Index.html:**

```
<div ng-include ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" src="'same.html'" data-id="1"></div>
<div ng-include ng-controller="JoystickCtrl" src="'same.html'" data-id="2"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function joystickCtrl($scope, $attrs) {
        $scope.id = $attrs.id;
    };
```

**View:**

```
<h2>Joystick: {{id}}</h2>
```

**[Here is the full code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XUdAAI?p=preview).**