# angularjs gives 'undefined' for hidden field with php session variable as value

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have found a lot or resources on how to pass a hidden input field value to an angularjs script, but not if that value is being read from a php session.

This is my html code:

```
    <div ng-controller="ImgCtrl">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="uid" value="<?=$_SESSION["uid"];?>" >
      <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" >
      <br/>
      <span>{{ message }}</span>
    </div>
```

I have also tried it as this:

```
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="uid" value="{{<?=$_SESSION["uid"];?>}}" >
```

**EDIT**
The angularjs code that will handle it is:

```
var ImgCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'image_upload.php', 
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'uid': $scope.uid
        },
        file: file
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = data;
      }).error(function(data, status) {
         alert(data);
      });
    }
  };
}];
```

Which was one of the answers I found, but I can not seem to find how to read a php session variable in angularjs.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to pass the value to a controller or a directive? (In other words, what are you doing with the value?)

Comment: I added the angular code that has to handle the hidden value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and easiest way to do what you are looking for is to basically create a global javascript variable and set the value in your PHP code. This will then get passed on to the controller. In the php page you would have:

```
<script>var serverVariable=<?=$_SESSION["uid"];?>;</script>
```

And in your controller you would have the line that says:

```
$scope.userId = serverVariable;
```

After that you can use the userId from scope wherever you would like and it will work! There is a plunker demonstrating this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7xEGM0Rz80TJQc0kPBwz?p=preview.

**Notes**

So, of course the easiest thing to do isn't always the best thing to do. First, if you are passing user id around client side - whether its in a hidden variable or if its in a javascript global **the client can manipulate your value**. You don't want to rely on whatever comes back from the client in your "post" or "put" then - but rather you should use the value that you have stored in session. This is a really good rule of thumb across the board for any sensitive values.

Another thing - this is the easiest but it is far from the only option. You might consider using the "ng-init" directive on the element where your controller is defined. You can find a stack question with that answer here: [Can you pass parameters to an AngularJS controller on creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523679/can-you-pass-parameters-to-an-angularjs-controller-on-creation). Again, simply pass the values in on the server side into your init routine and everything should get passed to the controller correctly!

I hope that my answer at least has set you on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking something about global variables and then I forgot completely about it, thanks works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

## angular.element

You could use `angular.element` to get an html element and with `val` you can read the value from the element without binding.

In your case it would be:

```php
<input type="hidden" id="uid" value="<?=$_SESSION["uid"];?>" >
```

```
angular.element("#uid").val();
```

## ng-init

With `ng-init` you can just init the model you want with the value you want.

In your case it would be :

```
<div ng-controller="ImgCtrl" ng-init="uid = <?=$_SESSION["uid"];?>" >
```