# How do I pass a value from one script to another script using angular js?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have two pages. The first page is a list of products. The second page is showing product details. The two pages have different ng-app and ng-controller.

Using ng-click the product id should be passed through the first script (first.js) to the second script (second.js) but I am unable to pull the product id into second script.

Please help me to solve the issue because I am newbie to angular JS.

Comment: if these two pages are part of one and the same app, why they have two different `ng-app`? you are missing `scope` fundamentals.

Comment: Hey, here are some tips for you: If you want help from the community you need to give a short piece of code to show what you have done so far. Also please use the search to check if the question has been asked before. Good luck with your code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: pass parameter between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760248/angularjs-pass-parameter-between-controllers)