# Why is the variable set in ng-init undefined in $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable I'm setting in my view with `ng-init` which I am then trying to access in my controller. When I try to access it however, I'm getting an `undefined`.

Relevant pieces of code:

My view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-init="pageTitle = 'kittens'">
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
var MyCtrl;

MyCtrl = function($scope) {
  return console.log($scope.pageTitle);
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewboni/WUzr9/3/)

What am I missing here?

Comment: that's because console.log() returns undefined, then you return that value as controller.

Comment: Have you missed the correct fiddle?

Comment: @ssilas777 apologies, please check again.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Wait until the variable is init.

```
$scope.$watch('pageTitle', function () {
    console.log($scope.pageTitle); 
});
```

Comment: I prefer `$timeout(function () { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 15):

You can also take advantage of how JavaScript defines functions and use a function for ng-init instead of $watch ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUzr9/49/)).

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="pageTitleEquals('kittens')">
        Page title is {{ pageTitle }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope) {   
    $scope.pageTitleEquals = function(title) {
        $scope.pageTitle = title;
    }
};
```

This question is similar: [How to set scope property with ng-init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981627/setting-scope-property-with-ng-init-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 12):

the controller is being created before the pageTitle variable is added to the $scope object.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing a "single time init", like a constructor I recommend you to unbind the watch after using the variable:

```
var pageTitleWatch = $scope.$watch('pageTitle', function () {
    console.log($scope.pageTitle);
    // Now just unbind it after doing your logic
    pageTitleWatch();
});
```