# How to set scope property with ng-init?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the value of a $scope property using ng-init, and I am unable to access that value in the controller's javascript. What am I doing wrong?  Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/uce3H/

markup:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="testController" >
        <input type="hidden" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" ng-init="testInput='value'" />
    </div>
    {{ testInput }}
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var testController = function ($scope) {
     console.log($scope.testInput);
}
```

In the javascrippt, $scope.testInput is undefined.  Shouldn't be 'value'?

Comment: all the answers are wrong about why this doesn't work. your code is fine, you are just binding to `testInput` outside of its scope, which is limited to the div above it. move `{{ testInput }}` up into the div, or move `ng-controller="testController"` up into the body tag.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are trying to read the set value before Angular is done assigning.

Demo:

```
var testController = function ($scope, $timeout) {
    console.log('test');
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log($scope.testInput);
    },1000);
}
```

Ideally you should use `$watch` as suggested by @Beterraba to get rid of the timer:

```
var testController = function ($scope) {
    console.log('test');
    $scope.$watch("testInput", function(){
        console.log($scope.testInput);
    });
}
```

Comment: You problably will want to use `$scope.$watch` in this case.

Comment: You could also use a `$watch` but keep in mind that the controller will run multiple times so whether you use a timeout or watch, it could run many times.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Somewhat surprising that angular allows this kind of race to happen in the first place, but I suppose it's hard to guard against!

Answer (score 39):

Just set ng-init as a function. You should not have to use watch.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-init="init('Blah')">{{ testInput }}</div>
</body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.testInput = null;
  $scope.init = function(value) {
    $scope.testInput= value;
  }
}]);
```

Here's an example.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F0tNkVK4LxfBSC6jb1vu?p=preview)

Comment: I like this, can't wait to try it out. I have been running into some issues using the $watch function.

Comment: This one is the best suggestion

Comment: its simple and you can use it in many ways, since you have the control over your function.

Comment: the ng-init in the body element is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="testController" >
        <input type="hidden" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" ng-init="testInput=123" />
    </div>
    {{ testInput }}
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App', []);

testController = function ($scope) {
    console.log('test');
    $scope.$watch('testInput', testShow, true);
    function testShow() {
      console.log($scope.testInput);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Psq/1/)

Comment: Sorry for my answer (too late) I now see that @Beterraba was first. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Like CodeHater said you are accessing the variable before it is set.

To fix this move the ng-init directive to the first div.

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="testInput='value'">
        <input type="hidden" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" />
       {{ testInput }}
    </div>
</body>
```

That should work!

Comment: Your {{ testInput }} is outside the scope of the controller and will most likely still be null :/  consider moving it up into the div

Comment: Yep, @Mutmatt it's a typo. I coded it directly here without much tought. Sorry

Comment: i am honored to be the first to upvote the first actual answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $http) {
       $scope.init = function(){           
       alert($scope.testInput);
   };});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myapp">
      <div ng-controller='testController' data-ng-init="testInput='value'; init();" class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9" >
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some trouble with `$scope.$watch` but after a lot of testing I found out that my `data-ng-model="User.UserName"` was badly named and after I changed it to `data-ng-model="UserName"` everything worked fine. I expect it to be the `.` in the name causing the issue.