# ng-init not working to initialize ng-model for textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-init

I am trying to initialize my model `discharge.total` with value 0,such that text box is by default populated with 0.
But textbox is not prepopulating.

- Please Note:
- I dont want model to initialize in controller.
- I have already    initialized `$scope.discharge = {}` in controller

---

```
<body ng-app>
     <div ng-controller="testController" >
        <input ng-init="discharge.total = 0 " class=" form-control" type="text" ng-model="discharge.total" disabled>       
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should init object in controller rather using `ng-init`.

Comment: @Vineet my controller has already list full of variable initialization.
I know its best practise but currently i am trying to achieve the solution this way.

Comment: Your code is working for me...

Comment: From angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit -  This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: since you have `$scope.discharge = {}` it is very simple to do this `$scope.discharge = {total: 0}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/53hznu57/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngInit is used to evaluate expressions. Check how its used [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h0pe5s5n/) though

```
 <div ng-init="discharge.total = 5">
        {{discharge.total}}
      </div>
```

check why yours  wont work is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981627/setting-scope-property-with-ng-init-doesnt-work)

```
  <input ng-init="discharge = 0 " class=" form-control"
 type="text" ng-model="discharge.total" disabled>{{discharge}}</input>
```

Comment: which way, it works with <div>, check the first fiddle. Also i edited it a little bit, [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k23ya4m9/) is this what you want ??