# angular call a function and pass id

Tags: angularjs, function, ng-init

How can i pas values to a function with ng-init in a angular project?
i have tried this and it works fine:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="myfunction(1)">
```

but the problem is, when i do this

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="myfunction({{id}})">
```

or

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="myfunction(id)">
```

it doesn't work!!
if i show the value of {{id}} in my template i get the id:  1
so the id does exist.

what is here the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981627/setting-scope-property-with-ng-init-doesnt-work.  Besides that, you are basically trying to call an init function on the controller, passing in a value from the controller?  Just access it directly from the init method.

Comment: First off, `{{id}}` is not meant to be passed as a parameter to the function. The function call is not going to interpolate that. Where is `id` initialized?

Comment: myFunction needs to be within scope.

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller?

Answer (score 1):

As Brendan Green mentioned, if `id` is a scope variable you don't need to pass it to the function. Would something like this work?

```
$scope.myfunction = function(){
  // do whatever with $scope.id
}
```

If you really need to use it as you are your third example should work. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SwT979KYcKGWdSjmaE1t).

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/frishi/HB7LU/22553/

Basically, pass in the variable itself to the function and not the interpolated value, i.e. `{{boo}}`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="boo=2">
  <div ng-click="foo(boo)">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the point of declaring the variable and then passing it in to an `ng-click`? You might as well just do `ng-click="foo(2)"`, which the OP already stated works in his `ng-init`.  The question is about passing a variable into `ng-init`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Thanks for correcting me! You are right.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `myfunction` in `ng-init`, the function should be defined in your `$scope`because ng-init evaluate expressions whatever they may be.

So here is what you should do:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init='myfunction("john");'>
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Mike';
  
  $scope.myfunction = function(otherName){
    $scope.name = otherName;
  };
});
```

**[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0n7CwWBPypnLuVJvvNE0?p=preview)**

Keep in mind that it is not recommended to use `ng-init` this way:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
> of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
> use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.