# How to inject a variable from scope into an Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In **index.html**, I am doing something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-model="pk" ng-init="pk='2'"></div>
</div>
```

Anyway, in my **angular** file, I am doing something like this:

```
.controller('MyController', [
  '$scope', function($scope) {
    alert('Sup ' + $scope.pk);
  }
])
```

So lets say the pk for a URL is 2, I expect to see something like this:

> Sup 2

However, my output is this :

> Sup undefined

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you manually write `ng-init="pk='2'"`?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work either :/

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: I think you shoud use ng-value not ng-init

Comment: ng-value does not work either. Oh and I updated the question to make it more simpler and easier to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting scope property with ng-init doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981627/setting-scope-property-with-ng-init-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay the alert with [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
.controller('myCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() 
      alert('Sup ' + $scope.pk);
    });
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens, because code from controller execute before code from view, so when run

```
alert('Sup ' + $scope.pk);
```

`ng-init` - not execute.

So, for solution, you can simple assign value inside controller, or use solution from other answers like `watch`, or `timeout`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

```
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('pk', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        alert('Sup ' + newValue);
    });
}]);
```

Your `alert('Sup ' + $scope.pk);` is called before the view has been initialized and therefore before `ng-init` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a trick that should always be followed: "Always use a dot in models".
For example:

`ng-model="models.pk"`

See more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong).

You should also consider following some [guidelines from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) that prevent that kind of problems, see [here](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) one example.
Try it and tell me how it went.