# Passing data between controllers using service and confusion with using [ '$scope' , 'service' , function($scope, service){}]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I am badly stuck with this problem of passing data from one controller to other in angularJS. Before my code was: whenever I click on templateController's div, it would trigger setTemplate with the help of ng-click... Now my objective was to send templateController's selected data to ReplyController...

After reading forum posts here, i decided to create a service called 'selectionService', so that i can transmit data between 2 controllers...

```
//Defined Service

proApp.service('selectionService', function() {
  var selected_template;

  addTemplate = function(newObj) {
      selected_template = newObj;
  };
  getTemplate = function(){
      return selected_template;
  };
});

//Controller 1... where templates are selected

proApp.controller('TemplateController',function($scope, selectionService)
{
    $scope.templates = [ 
    {template_name:"Template 1", template_text:"We apologize for the interruption."} ,
    {template_name:"Template 2", template_text:"Thank you for contacting us."} ,
    } ,
    ];

    // on ng-click
    $scope.setTemplate = function(tmp)
    {
        selectionService.addTemplate(tmp);   
    }
});


// Controller 2 ... supposed to catch the selected template.

proApp.controller('ReplyController', function($scope, selectionService) 
{
    $scope.template = selectionService.getTemplate();
});
```

So whenever i run this code, i started getting this error

```
Object [object Object] has no method addTemplate...
```

Again I tweeked the code where they were suggesting to use Squarebrackets and put $scope , servicename and then write function with same parameters.. I don't understand why I should do this? Event after doing some changes like
 `[ '$scope' , 'service' , function($scope, service){}]` ,

I am still not able to figure out the solution to pass data from one controller to other using service.

Could you help? What am I missing? I am very new to angularJS way of doing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's actually quite simple. You just need to add your methods to the service by using `this.`. Currently they are declared on `window`. Change your service declaration to use `this`...

```
proApp.service('selectionService', function() {
  var selected_template;

  this.addTemplate = function(newObj) {
      selected_template = newObj;
  };
  this.getTemplate = function(){
      return selected_template;
  };
});
```

As for using the array notation for dependencies, it's a good practice but it's not required. It'll save you from headaches if you ever run your code through a minifier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anthony. That is how I did, whenever I call selectionService.getTemplate() from the other controller.. it says Object [object Object] has no method getTemplate

Comment: Did you add the "`this`" keyword to your 2 function declarations? They're missing in your original code.

Comment: Anthony , i had missed that detail, i added this keyword now... Now the error is not appearing.. But still it is not solving my problem.. how to get the value $scope.template = selectionService.getTemplate(); ... when i did console.log() .. the value is undefined ... that means getTemplate() is returning nothing?

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside `setTemplate()` and see what value is being passed in and see if `selected_Template` is being set to it.

Comment: How do I refresh the data in ReplyController on every ng-click data which is carried by the service.. it seems like it is triggering only once.. how do i keep it updated... i followed this question for a while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js .. should we use ng-model to update data dynamically... i am currently using just { template } in  controller's jade file ..

Comment: It looks like they are suggesting you broadcast an event from addTempate() and listen for it in your reply controller.

Comment: actually, i was about to ask the same question....the events are being recorded inside addTemplate() ... i just did console.log and was able to see  selected template... now i want to know how to propogate this template to replyController... do u know how to broadcast this? i am asking too many questions.. I am sorry...

Comment: Change your service to take in `$rootScope` as a parameter, then in `addTemplate()`, use `$rootScope.$broadcast(...)` to broadcast an event. And in the reply controller, add `$scope.$on(...)` to listen for it and set `$scope.template = selectionService.getTemplate();`.

Comment: Wow.. $rootScope and $broadcast stuff now worked! wow finally.. able to get all click events propagated to reply controller :) thanks a lot anthony..

Comment: It feels like there must be a more elegant way to do this though. But I'm glad to hear it worked out for you.