# Access service data changed in anonymous function after controller switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I simplified my actual code but the problem is the same. After you click `Start counter` anonymous function in "First controller" starts changing data inside `myService`. First it works ok. But after switching to "Second controller" Angular stops auto-updating value of `<span ng-bind="getData().data">` even if you navigate back to "First controller".

However if you switch controllers back and forth a bit you can see that span is updating on controller load so data is changing and controllers can access it. It's just Angular not auto-tracking it anymore.

How can I make Angular to start tracking changes and update element after switching controllers again?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="padding: 0 0 20px 0">
    <a href="#/first">First controller</a> | <a href="#/second">Second controller</a>
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="temp1.html">
        Data: <span ng-bind="getData().data"></span>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="start()">Start counter</button>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="temp2.html">
        Data: <span ng-bind="getData().data"></span>
    </script>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

    myControllers.factory('myService', [function() {
        return { data: 0 };
    }]);

    myControllers.controller('myController1', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
        $scope.getData = function() {
            return myService;
        }

        $scope.start = function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                myService.data++;
                $scope.$apply();    
            }, 1000)
        }
    }]);

    myControllers.controller('myController2', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
        $scope.getData = function() {
            return myService;
        }
    }]);

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'myControllers'
    ]);

    myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/first",{ controller: "myController1", templateUrl: "temp1.html"}).
            when("/second", {controller: "myController2", templateUrl: "temp2.html"}).
            otherwise({redirectTo : "/first"});
    }]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the interval in the controller, and not in the service itself? Also, you should use `$interval`, rather than `setInterval` to avoid having to do `$scope.apply`

Comment: I'm doing setTimeout to emulate what's happening in my real application. I'm writing node-webkit app and instead of setTimeout there really is a child_process.on('data', callback) handler. 
Using $timeout solves the problem in **this** case but I really need more generic case that would work with any callback function. **Note:** I can append another $interval to the Controller1 to would forcibly call $scope.$apply() every 100 msec no matter what but that looks ugly. I think I need to properly reference $scope from callback function so that it would target current $scope instance all the time.

Comment: what exactly is the nature of `child_process.on()`? If it's a listener, you could re-subscribe. I would also encourage you to use a service and start/end listeners there, and not rely on a controller life cycle

Comment: Child process is a real child process running in background. `child_process.stdout.on()` is an event listener triggered  when child process spits out something into stdout. Re-subscribing may work. Thanks I'll think about it though it's gonna take lot's of additional code and I thought there should be an easier way.

Comment: Doing this inside a service *is* the easier way

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I agree that it is better to do it inside service but  it does not solve initial issue. Even if I create setter inside the service `$scope` will not auto-update bound elements after unload-load. I actually found an answer that suits me. Thanks for your time and regards! Your comments actually put me to the right googling route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually found an answer here: [Passing data between controllers using service and confusion with using [ '$scope' , 'service' , function($scope, service){}]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821228/passing-data-between-controllers-using-service-and-confusion-with-using-scop#comment-33026165) (see comment from *Anthony Chu Feb 17 '14 at 6:12*). The trick is in using `$rootController` to alert all other controllers via event to update data from service. So anonymous function will run in background without having reference to the new `$scope` but new `$scope` will receive messages from it via `$rootScope` event down propagation.

I've appended `$root.$broadcast(...)` to anonymous function and appended respective `$scope.$on(...)` to both controllers. So controllers code now looks like this:

```
myControllers.controller('myController1', ['$scope', 'myService', '$interval', '$rootScope', 
  function($scope, myService, $interval, $rootScope) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
      return myService;
    }

    $scope.$on('myupdate', function() {
      if (!$scope.$$phase) { //checks that Angular is not updating scope right now
        $scope.$apply();
      }        
    });

    $scope.start = function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        myService.data++;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myupdate');
      }, 1000)
    }
}]);

myControllers.controller('myController2', ['$scope', 'myService',
  function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
      return myService;
    }

    $scope.$on('myupdate', function() {
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
      }        
    });
}]);
```

[Fully working code example](https://github.com/achekulaev/code-examples/blob/master/angular-controllers-service.html).