# How to access the scope outside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

On the navigation bar, I have a shopping cart snapshot (total items, total price) which uses `$scope.cart`.

In the `ng-view`, there are pages to add/remove items in the shopping cart.

It appears that `ng-view` created an isolated scope. If I add items into `$scope.cart`, it goes to the scope that belongs to `ng-view`. How can `ng-view` share the parent scope?

Answer (score 1):

The `$scope` exists inside the `ng-controller`. The `ng-view` directive only tells to Angular JS the place where partials will be loaded. You have couple of ways to archive this cart in another place outside, as:

**1)** You can create an outter contoller with `$scope.cart` and propagate from the inner controller the value, using the same variable name.

- [AngularJS–Part 3, Inheritance](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2013/12/10/angularjspart-3-inheritance/)

**2)** Another way could be using a `Service`, that's singleton in Angular JS, to set the cart and then change it in the inner controller, to propagate to the outter one.

- [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)