# Need to pass $scope with variables to another page in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this routes:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })
            .when('/next', {
              templateUrl: 'views/next.html',
              controller: 'MainCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'main'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
```

When I'm in main page. I clicking to next button and see 'views/next.html'. But I'm not have my previously $scope. How I can get this scope?

Comment: the best here is to use service

Comment: Maybe you should create a Factory\Service and store all needed data here? And get data through any controller you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591837/angularjs-store-data-factory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New route renders new template and also bind new scope to template. So you can't really just use the same scope for both routes. However, there are at least two workarounds.

1). **$rootScope**. `$rootScope` is available in all views so you can store some data in it and be able to access it in any template.

2). **Service**. Use shared service in both controllers. This is probably optimal solution for most cases.

Comment: (+ONE) thought of shared service!!

Comment: I really dislike $rootScope that make application hard to maintain but the Service way is exactly how it should be done.

Comment: @Okazari I wouldn't use `$rootScope` too in this case, but still this is one way, not optimal but possible.

Comment: @dfsq Just add a warning and this will be perfect then :) because actually it can sound like a pretty good solution despite it's not.

Comment: Thank you! I create service - app.value('name', []);