# How to pass object with ui router between controllers in a $state angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [this generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-with-browserify).

I have my user module:

```
require('angular/angular');
require('angular-ui-router');


angular.module('userModule', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {


    $stateProvider
        .state('utenti', {
            url: '/utenti',
            templateUrl: 'src/utenti/views/utenti.tpl.html',
            controller: 'RegistrationCrl',    
        })

        .state('access', {
            url: '/access',
            templateUrl: 'src/utenti/views/access.tpl.html',
            controller: 'AccessCtrl',
        });


}])
.controller('RegistrationCrl', require('./controllers/registrationLogin'))
.controller('AccessCtrl', require('./controllers/access'));
```

In my RegistrationCrl I use a service to create a new member:

```
module.exports = function($scope, User, Member, $state, $location,$rootScope, $stateParams){
        $scope.registration = function(form){
            if(!form.$valid ){
                console.log('input error');
                return;
            }
            else{
                console.log('valid form');

                Member.create($scope.newMember,
                    function(data){
                        $state.go('access', data); 
                    },
                    function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                );

            }
        };
    };
```

I would like to use that data in my next view related to the accessCtl.  I don't want to use the id in my URL and using the $stateParams.

My access controller is:

```
module.exports =  function($scope, User, Member, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams){
        console.log($state);
        console.log($stateParams);
    };
```

In that console.log I don't find my object passed with $state.go.

Comment: Can't you pass your data in `$state` as you pass the `controller`? `.state('access', {
            url: '/access',
            templateUrl: 'src/utenti/views/access.tpl.html',
            controller: 'AccessCtrl',
            newData: 'whatever'
        });`

It works with routes.

Comment: I have read about that but what i miss is how to put my data result from the registration in the newData property, what should i write in my registrationCrl? $state.go('access', {newData:data} ?

Comment: Oh, I've misunderstood you. I thought you were trying to pass a fixed value to your controller. So, I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

You can $stateParams to pass data to next view.
Add param in target route

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('utenti', {
        url: '/utenti',
        templateUrl: 'src/utenti/views/utenti.tpl.html', 
        params: { myParam: null},
        controller: 'RegistrationCrl',    
    })
```

Pass data to next view

```
  $state.go("utenti",{myParam:{"data":"data"}})
```

And get data in next controller

```
         $scope.paramDetails=$stateParams.myParam;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you can't pass objects between states as params. One option is to use a `service` which is accessible by all controllers that you inject it into.

There is a good answer already on SO for sharing a `service` [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: I have read that answer but using a controller can be a bit messy. If i need to use this data in more views i have to add a function or a nee service every time. If i can't pass objects, can i pass some attributes of the objects?

Comment: Pass some reference to the data and then search for it on your backend perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the resolve statement for ui.router

```
 resolve:{
      data: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
          return $stateParams.data;
      }]
```

Comment: I use the resolve statement in my access state. But in my other controller (RegistrationCtr) how do i assign that data to my data? :) $state.go('access', data) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set though the state param.

```
$state.get('details').Obj= {};
$state.go('details);
```

the access like below in the another controller which is attached to this state.

```
$state.get('details').Obj
```