# Get controller value in app.js from controller.js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

Can anyone help me to pass the variable 
$scope.imageRepoUrl from controller.js to app.js

controller.js

```
    .controller('deallistCtrl', ['$scope','deals', function($scope, deals) {
        $scope.title = "test";
        $scope.deals = deals.payload;
        $scope.imageRepoUrl=$scope.$parent.imageRepoUrl;
        $scope.appWebUrl=$scope.$parent.appWebUrl;

    }])
```

app.js

```
  .state('app.deallists', {
    url: "/deallists",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/deallists.html",
        controller: 'deallistCtrl',
        resolve: {
            deals: ['$http', function($http){
                return $http.get('deal/deals').then(function(response){
                    return response.data;   
                })
            }]
        }
      }
    }, 
  })
```

Comment: The file names themselves mean very little. What in app.js needs this value? If the value is provided by the user, the controller could "hang" the value onto `$rootScope`.

Comment: This is a phonegap application with ionic framework, i have added `angular.module('sample.controllers', [])
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.appWebUrl= 'http://URL';
 //global variable
})` in controller.js  , this will be accessible in controller methods with the help of scope . `$scope.$parent.appWebUrl` what we need is to get the data in app.js

Comment: *What/where*  in `app.js` do you need this URL? Any reason why you can't define it in a `.constant`?

Comment: thanks @NewDev am pretty new to angular , your input helps

Comment: [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20181396/456814)