# Angular route menu active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to explain my problem in advance sorry for my bad english.

I have written code with angular and angular route
My navbar looks like this in html

```
<ul nav-menu>
    <li><a href="">Index</a></li>
    /*others*/
</ul>
```

And route params

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl' 
        })
        .when('/skills', {
            // others
        })
```

Everything works perfectly but my questin is:

**How can I set some css to my `li` element when route has been loaded or active?**

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy with Angular.

You can define a controller for the NavBar as below,

```
<ul nav-menu ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <li ng-class={active : isRouteActive("/home")}><a href="/home">Index</a></li>        
</ul>
```

Then your controller should defined as below,

```
app.module("myApp",["ngRoute"])
  .controller("NavbarCtrl", function($scope, $location) {

   $scope.isRouteActive = function(route) { 
        var curRoute = $location.path();
        return curRoute.match(route);
    }

});
```

If you are using UI Router it's just a matter of adding an attribute like below,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
```

This will make the item highlighted automatically when the current state matches.

Hope this helps

~Ragesh

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with **more than topic** here.

> 1. First, have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). There you can put Angular logic inside the class, so it's changing with the scope values or
>      function returns.
> 2. Therefore you have to deal with passing scopes and data through controllers, or depending how your app is structured.

For the second topic, [here is a good SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js) which explains it pretty well.

Comment: ng-class not work for me because every elements seperated differently? Is there any way similar to  `ng active` when url have been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

In angular UI there's a component (Angular UI) that checks whether the route is currently active or not:
Here's an example from its documentation: [Angular-UI Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

```
<a ui-route="/page" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">link</a>
```

What it simply means is, when the route in the *ui-route* is currently accessed, the class *active* should be enabled.

If you wanna do it using angular only, you can do it like this.

```
<li><a ng-href="/home" ng-class="{'active: $location.path() ==='/home'}">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller that is attach to menu, inject `$state`. This will give information about state You are in right now. `ng-class="active: $state === actual_state_name"`
will set active class . I guess after inject You can use $state in view, but You need to check it by Yourself.

Another solution, not in angular way is getting javascript `window` object. Similar is $location, whitch provide info about actual link and other cool features