# Setting the menu active based on the URL in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, menu

I am working on an angular app with a top menu and i need to set the menu active based on the url. Here is what i have tried.

**URL example**

http://localhost:4200/home/about - About should be highlighted

http://localhost:4200/home/service/supply - Service should be highlighted

http://localhost:4200/home/contact/details- Contact should be highlighted

```
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.currentMenu = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.nav-link'); 
      for (let i = 0; i < this.currentMenu.length; i++) {
        if(event.url.indexOf('/about') > -1){
          if(this.currentMenu[i].innerHTML == "About"){
            this.currentMenu[i].style.color  = "red";
          } 
        } else if (event.url.indexOf('/service') > -1){
          if(this.currentMenu[i].innerHTML == "Service"){
            this.currentMenu[i].style.color  = "red";
          } 
        }
        else if (event.url.indexOf('/contact') > -1){
            if(this.currentMenu[i].innerHTML == "Contact"){
              this.currentMenu[i].style.color  = "red";
            } 
          }
      }
    }
  })
```

I am not sure whether this is the right approach to achieve this. any inputs will be highly appreciated

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/29696210/1128441

Answer (score 0):

No need to do the long way you've done as the `Angular Library` provides an easy and efficient solution to this.

Since you said you're dealing with `Menu` options, please use  `routerLinkActive` and `routerLinkActiveOptions` directives here as below: -

Option 1:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

Option 2:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="class1 class2">Bob</a>
<a routerLink="/user/bob" [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2']">Bob</a>
```

Option 3:

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
  <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
</div>
```

Use as per your requirements. More details can be found here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerlinkactive