# Can Ionic menu and menu content uses same controller

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic-side-menus directive for several pages, each with its own menu, can the content and menu page use the same controller in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, add the same controller in `ui router` to the views you want to share the same controller with (`app.js`)

Check out the following [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBHHuo?p=preview) (standard side menu template from ionic)

*#app.js*

`app` state (menu.html) and `app.playlists` (playlists.html) shares the same controller (`PlaylistCtrl`)

*#controllers.js*

in `PlaylistCtrl` has two variables accessed by the side menu and the main page.

HTH

Comment: But the problem would be the controller is loaded twice

Comment: @user2412555, If you want to share data between different controllers, they probably you might want to use a `service` have a look that this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Comment: Ye, I was forced to create a separated controller and communicate through service or broadcast message.