# Passing a value from one controller to another one

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a value from one controller to another one.
Example: page 1(*controller A*) has 5 lists of values. I clicked the 3rd value and so I am directed to page 2(*controller B*). Here I need to get data based on the value I clicked in the page 1(*controller A*).

Example:

```
page 1 list of students 
id   name    
1    mark
2    Dev
3    Nancy 

page 2 details of student
    name=mark
    subject  grade
    English  A
    Spanish  A-
```

I am using spring-hibernate to get data from a database.

Comment: Communicate data through services, and inject the service in both controllers

Comment: See http://www.theroks.com/angularjs-communication-controllers/ and http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/xqdxg/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Comment: @Navaneeth  i did same as in the jsfiddle, but i got this error

    **ReferenceError : controller is not defined**
can you help me with this

Answer (score 3):

You can create a service to store this object

```
angular.module('app').factory('StoreService', function () {
        var storedObject;
        return {
            set: function (o) {
                this.storedObject = o;
            },
            get: function () {
                return this.storedObject;
            }
        };
});
```

and then inject it in both controllers.

```
angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', function ($scope, StoreService) {
    $scope.setValue = function (value) {
        StoreService.set(value);
    };
});

angular.module('app').controller('SecondController', function ($scope, StoreService) {
    $scope.getValue = function () {
        $scope.value = StoreService.get();
    };
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to inject it to the controllers.

Comment: @flyingkandi I updated my answer with that information

Comment: thank you @kTT.
the value is passed form 'firstController' to storeObject.set(o="abc").
but after that i am redirected to page2.jsp. at that moment the value in o(o="abc") is no more there in the o.
can you please look into this

Comment: @flyingkandi How you make your redirect? Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ctawL4t3/, I set and get value between two controllers.