# Angularjs pass parameters so they are hidden

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know how what is the best (and most secure) way to pass parameters (such as product id) between views so the user cannot see them in the url bar.

Thank you.
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass them from one controller to another controller in the new view. Here is a pretty good answer on how to do that: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a shared service and use them when you need them, quick sample:

```
app.factory("shared", function() {
    var data = null;
    return {
        setData: function(someData) {
            data = someData;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

And now use it!

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, shared) {
    $scope.data = shared.getData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to use the Angular Service pattern.
Because the controllers are functions and the services are objects (singletons) You can have multiples services according to the differents functionnalities that you have in your app.

You should see the documentation for Angular providers here :
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers