# Controller scope share?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have in my index.html two separate places where I declare:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController>
    <div id="box1" ng-controller="SameController">
        Box1 {{test}} <button ng-click="changeMe()">Click</button>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" ng-controller="SameController">
        Box2 {{test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Initially in SameController, $scope.test = "One"
I want to make it so that when the user clicks the "Click" button, then {{test}} text will change to "Two" in both places (box1 and box2) (what the changeMe function does).

The problem is when I click, only the message in "Box1" changes to "Two", but not the message in "Box2". I tried using: $scope.$parent.test = "One" and make it so that SameController points to it, but it does not seem to work either.

How can I get around this so that both box1 and box2 change the text content of {{test}} when the button is clicked? The more elegant the solution the better.

Comment: Why not just wrap box1 and box2 in the same element with SameController on it?

Comment: Im simplifying the example, but the reason is because there are other controllers/directives, html that are in the middle, position styling applied that does not lend itself to wrapping both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js you just use a service to share data between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element with `ng-controller` directive has its own scope, and they are not connected in any way. The most elegant solution is to set up a service for common application data.

```
app.value('commonData', {});    
app.controller('SameController', function ($scope, commonData) {
  $scope.data = commonData;
  $scope.changeMe = function () {
    $scope.data.test = 'test';
  }
});
```

And use it like this

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController>
<div id="box1" ng-controller="SameController">
Box1 {{data.test}} <button ng-click="changeMe()">Click</button>
</div>

<div id="box2" ng-controller="SameController">
Box2 {{data.test}}
</div>
</div>
```

You can also hold common data in parent scope, but it is not recommended because both `SameController` are forced to be direct descendants of the same parent directive this way.