# View not updating with added user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-material

I am trying to add a user (which succesfully works in the backend. users get added to my db) but my view will not update when the user is added to the db.

I am working with Angular and Node for my backend.

I must mention that my form for adding a user is in a popup box (md-dialog --> angular material) but this should not be an issue as to why the view won't update properly. The user will show up in the list once I refresh my browser.

my code for adding the user (app.js)

```
//Function to add a user to the db
$scope.inviteUser = function(){
    $http.post('/api/users/invite', {
        'email': $scope.user.email,
        'role_id': $scope.user.role
    }, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Successfully saved a user to the DB", data);

        //$scope.userInfo = data;
        $scope.userInfo.push(data);

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to add user to DB");
    });
}
```

addUser.tmpl.html

```
  <md-dialog aria-label="" ng-controller="CalendarCtrl">
    <form name="form"  >
      <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <h1 class="customH1">Invite a user</h1>

          <span flex></span>
          <!-- <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="closeDialog()">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="images/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
          </md-button> -->
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-dialog-content>
        <div id="containerForm">
            <div layout="row">
              <md-input-container flex="">
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': form.email.$valid && submitted,'has-error': form.email.$invalid && submitted }">
                  <label>Enter the user's e-mail</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="to" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required mongoose-error/>
                  <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.email && submitted">
                    Doesn't look like a valid email.
                  </p>
                  <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.required && submitted">
                    What's your email address?
                  </p>
                  <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.email.$error.mongoose">
                    {{ errors.email }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>  

            <br /><br />

            <div ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$valid">
              <h5>Assign one of the following role's:</h5>

              <div id="wrapperRadioButtons">
                <md-radio-group ng-model="user.role">
                  <md-radio-button ng-repeat="userrole in roleInfo" value="{{userrole.id}}" class="md-primary">{{userrole.role}}</md-radio-button>
                </md-radio-group>
              </div>
              </div>

            <br />

        </div>
      </md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-actions" layout="row" >
        <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">Cancel</md-button>

        <md-button id="send_email" ng-click="inviteUser(); closeDialog()" class="md-primary">Invite</md-button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-dialog>
```

Comment: dialog has it's own controller. How is `$scope.userInfo` in dialog controller connected to controller in other part of view?

Comment: I have two questions: is the success function after post actually retrieving any data, as in: is your server sending the user back? Secondly are you adding to the $scope.userinfo in the popup controller and expecting it to show up in its parent controller? (that won't work)

Comment: yes so when i add a user the data is send to the server and store in the db but i was also expecting that my user list would update automatically with the newly created user. http://gyazo.com/f2a7ac28f0680be22fdf2bb255f4cde4

Comment: @charlietfl, through my ng-controller="CalendarCtrl" that is define at the top in my addUser.tmpl.html

Comment: You'll have to , like you're trying, to push the object into the array. But I'm suspecting, like @charlietfl, that you're actually pushing the new user in an array bound to the popup controller's $scope. The controller that handles the view / display of users , isn't using the same array. (That's my guess)

Comment: You are missing the point. Controllers each have there own `$scope`. Where does `$scope.userInfo` get defined in the CalendarCtrl? Is it through a service? Show the full controller

Comment: They have a parent - child relation @charlietfl , so prototypal inheritance is operative. Meaning that the the child controller will also look for properties in the parents scope but not the other way around.

Comment: @skubski I rather doubt that for a dialog there is a parent/child relationship

Comment: @charlietfl it is always possible to set an objects prototype, irrelevant in this case however. But yes, a service would be more appropriate to share data, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the userInfo property in the $scope of CalendarCtrl, but based on the HTML you posted, there is no such property in that $scope. If userInfo belongs to a different $scope, then you can either:

1. Assign the returned data to the $rootScope so that that other $scope can use it; not recommended (see below).
2. Use a service to pass the data to the other $scope; this is the preferred approach because it does not pollute the global $rootScope. See [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js) for this approach.

Comment: You can also emit an event with data! But that also isn't really recommended. ;)

Comment: no point even suggesting `$rootScope` ... ugly shortcut that can easily get abused

Answer (score 0):

The popup box is irrelevant in this case. 
You should bind the data in the controller to a service and it will automatically reflect in the page without refreshing the page, just update the user list in the service after adding the new user.

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851792/3480671) and take a look at the fiddle for a detailed example for your service.