# Can't navigate to correct path using $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my index.html within ng-repeat I have a tag like this

```
<li><a ng-click="viewJobs(employer)">View Job Listing</a></li>
```

then in my controller I do

```
$scope.viewJobs = function(user){
    $location.path('/employers/jobs/' + user.user.id);
}
```

My route config

```
.when('/employers/jobs/user_guid',{
        templateUrl : '/myTemplate/employers/jobs.html',
        controller : 'employersJobController'
    })
```

When I click on the link it go to `http://localhost/#/`, I wonder what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route config should be (and the param should start with a `:`),

```
.when('/employers/jobs/:id',{
        templateUrl : '/myTemplate/employers/jobs.html',
        controller : 'employersJobController'
    })
```

*Note :* the parameter you are passing from the controller and the routing param must be same (by name).

for,

```
$location.path('/employers/jobs/' + user.user.myId);
```

the route config will be,

```
.when('/employers/jobs/:myId',{
        templateUrl : '/myTemplate/employers/jobs.html',
        controller : 'employersJobController'
    })
```

Comment: One question Ashad, what if I want to hide the param? it's a guid, so I think it shouldn't exposed to the public.

Comment: in that case you can't have a state that contains id. Make a new state without id and call it. like, `/employes/jobs/detail` and use `service` to share data between controllers.

Comment: a quick search got me this     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js