# how to redirect the selected json value to another page using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-if="usernames.length" ng-repeat="user in usernames">
        <td><input type="radio" name="radio"  ng-model="form.currentPatient" value="{{user}}" id="{{user.id}}"></td>
            <td>{{user.firstname}} </td>
            <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.address}}</td>
            <td>{{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>



    </table>
    <div>{{form.currentPatient}}</div>
   <button type="submit" value="View Profile" onclick="location.href('result.html' )">View Profile</button>
```

If I click on that radio button ,the corresponding json values should be redirect to the result page
Please help me ......

Comment: are you using `ngRoute` or `ui-route`

Comment: <tr ng-if="usernames.length" ng-repeat="user in usernames">
  <td><input type="radio" name="radio"  ng-model="form.currentPatient" value="{{user}}" id="{{user.id}}"></td>
            <td>{{user.firstname}} </td>
   <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
   <td>{{user.address}}</td>
   <td>{{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
 <div>{{form.currentPatient}}</div>
   <button type="submit" value="View Profile" onclick="location.href('result.html' )">View Profile</button>

Comment: @AshadShanto I guess the user is not using any routing module

Comment: Create a factory, store that json value there and fetch it using existed factory in another controller which has access to the new page.

Comment: in that case try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js 

pass data through a service.

Answer (score 0):

**If not using routeprovider**

You can create shared service or factory to store value and retrive in other pages.

**If using routeprovider**

You can bind JSON value in URl this way-:

```
window.location="#/result/firstname="+$scope.user.firstname+"&&lastname="+$scope.user.lastname+"&&age="+$scope.user.age; And You can access this value as $location.search()['firstname'], $location.search()['lastname'], $location.search()['age']
```

you can access this value as-:
         $location.search()['firstname']  for firstname,
        $location.search()['lastname'] for lastname   and
        $location.search()['age'] for age
you can add $location in function like as $scope .

Comment: The table will display values of searched user from json. I want to get only one row value from the table when I click the radio button ie.The details of particular user and that value should be redirect to another page...

Comment: <table ng-repeat="tabledata in ListJson> <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-change='getRadioBtnData(tabledata)'> </table>  then  $scope.getRadioBtnData=function(data){//then set the data appropriate url}

Comment: If example $scope.ListJson have an search results.   <table ng-repeat="tabledata in ListJson> <input type="radio" ng-model="value" ng-change='getRadioBtnData(tabledata)'> </table>  then  $scope.getRadioBtnData=function(data){//then set the data to appropriate url}