# AngularJS: Setting Global Variable AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am looking for best practices with AngularJS:
I need to share a json ajax response between nested controllers.
Controller1->Controller2->Controller3

Right now I have a working version that simply sets a $scope.variable with the response in controller1, and the other controllers access it by calling the same variable.

I have tried creating a global service, but the problem is I make the ajax call in a controller, and before the ajax call is finished, the global variable defaults to null for all the other controllers.

I am just trying to understand what best approach is in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create publisher/subscriber service or factory and subscribe methods from your controller2 and 3 to data change. Just like this:

```js
angular
  .module('')
  .factory('GlobalAjaxVariable', function() {
    var subscribers = [];

    function publish(data) {
      callbacks.forEach(function(clb) {
        clb(data);
      });
    }

    return {
      setData: function(ajaxData) {
        publish(ajaxData);
      },

      addSubscriber: function(clb) {
        subscribers.push(clb);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Yuri.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the value in `$rootScope.variable` and after access it from any other controller (as `$scope.variable`)