# AngularJS Communication between different-2 Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers `ConfigurationController.js` and `CartController.js`. I want to pass `configuration` data to `cart`.

I tried using below:-

> $rootScope.value1 = '---';
>
> $rootScope.value2 = '---';
>
> $rootScope.value3 = '---';
>
> and so on...............

But it will increase `$rootScope` size in browser memory and even forth and back we have to manage `$rootScope` value.

```
Is any other way in AngularJS that I can handle same situation in better way.
```

Comment: use service or factory

Comment: Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js

Comment: Thanks, This may be a good idea, Let me try this.

Comment: Still trying to use service, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In angularJS this the way where you can pass value between the controller.js.

```
Othen than that you can use any StateServer technique, if data is growing in any size.
```

But both `$scope` or `$rootscope` will carry same memory, just way of communication is different.

Comment: Yup, I also got same idea, but still looking for some thing that will sort out this issue.