# pass parameter from one controller to another page controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
.controller('ExplorerCtrl', ["$scope", "appServices","$location", 'appSettings', function ($scope, appServices, $location, appSettings) {
 $scope.changeLocation = function() {
    $location.path('career'?name={{career.Name}});   
  };
  $scope.getCareerList = function(){
      appServices.doAPIRequest(appSettings.appAPI.career.overviewList, null, null).then(function(data){
       $scope.allCareer = data.data.n;
      })
    };
```

How to pass parameter from one controller to another page controller. the career.name I want to b appended in my next page API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: store and get it from localstorage or sessionstorage