# Using AngularJs Service in more than one controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling with angular here. What I learned is that factory and service functions of a module create only one instance of an object associating properties ( functions and variables) with it. And that that instance is available throughout the controllers of the application.

In my app I have created a service module `userAngService` as follows:

```
var ser = angular.module('userAngService',[]);

ser.service('userAngService',['$cookies','$location','$http','$log','$rootScope',function($cookies,$location,$http,$log,$rootScope){
    this.user = {};
    $rootScope.username = {};
    $rootScope.user = {};

    /*this.loadUserData = function(username){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/webapi/profiles/'+username
        }).success(function(data){
            user = data.data;
            //return user;
        });
    };*/

    this.login = function(val){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/webapi/stories?username='+val.username+'&password='+val.password
        }).then(function(data){
            if(data.data==="Success"){
                $rootScope.username = val.username;
                $cookies.put("username", val.username);
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/webapi/profiles/'+val.username
                }).success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    this.user = data;
                    console.log(this.user);
                });
                $location.path("/home");
            }else{
                window.alert('Wrong username or password');
            }
        });
    };

    this.logout = function(){
        $rootScope.user.username = "";
        $cookies.remove("username");
        $location.path("/Diary");
    };

    this.addToShelf = function(wsPublish){
        wsPublish.author = $rootScope.user.username;
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/webapi/stories',
            data: wsPublish
        }).then(function(data){
            this.user.stories.push(data.data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

It contains 3 functions and private variable `this.user` and 2 rootScope variables `$rootScope.username` & `$rootScope.user`.
Our concerned function is `this.login()` function here.

Now,

To use this service module I created a module `AllControllers`:

```
 var app = angular.module('AllControllers',['userAngService']);
```

and I associated **2 controllers** with it.

**First controller:**

```
app.controller('LoginFormController',['$cookies','$rootScope','$log','$scope','userAngService','userBean',function($cookies,$rootScope,$log,$scope,userAngService,userBean){

    $scope.login = function(val){
        userAngService.login(val);
    };

    $scope.logout = function(){
        userAngService.logout();
    };

    $scope.publishGroup = function(obj){
        userBean.publishGroup(obj);
    };
}]);
```

***This controller is injected with dependency of `userAngService` and it's `login()` function delegates a call to `login() function of userAngService` service**

The `login()` function in `userAngService` changes its private variables properties.
Which then I am trying to use in another controller and that's where all the problem is.
When I am logging the returned `promise` data in `userAngService` itself, it is logging successfully but when I try to access in another controller, it just logs an **empty object**

**Second Controller (from where accessing the service's private variables) :**

```
 app.controller('ReachController',['$cookies','$scope','$rootScope','userAngService',function($cookies,$scope,$rootScope,userAngService){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.username = {};

    $scope.user = userAngService.user;
    console.log(userAngService.user);
    $scope.username = $cookies.get("username");

    /*userAngService.loadUserData($scope.username).then(function(data){
        $scope.user = data.data;
        console.log($scope.user);
    });*/

    console.log($scope.user);
    console.log($rootScope.user);

    $scope.logout = function(){
        userAngService.logout();
    };

    $scope.addToShelf = function(wsPublish){
        userAngService.addToShelf(wsPublish);
    };
}]);
```

Well an empty object can only mean that the object properties are defined to null and are not updated by `login()` function of service. However, in `userAndService` withing `success` callback;

```
console.log(data);
this.user = data;
console.log(this.user);
```

these lines of code successfully log returned data, while in `ReachController` or **Second Controller**'s lines;

```
$scope.user = userAngService.user;
...
console.log($scope.user);
```

logs this to console:

```
Object {}
```

There are no errors so code is right but then something wrong conceptually I guess. Please help!

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/trollr/rjuvagb9/6/ is a working ng 1.5 example with 2 controllers and a component. Maybe it's helpful if you compare it

Comment: May be this will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433439/angular-pass-info-from-array-from-one-controller-to-another/36433895#36433895

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return a data use factory instead of service.

Service always returns a methods with data.

```
console.log(data);
this.user = data;
console.log(this.user);
```

"this" object is for local scope of Success function. it will overridden service "this" object.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is in the same naming of service and parent module - `userAngService`. Try renaming module to `userAngServiceModule`. I would expect angular's DI to get confused whether you are referring to module or service when you add dependency to `userAngService`.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` context inside a promise `.then` handler is not the same as the `this` context of a service.

```
app.service("myService", function($http) {
    var myService = this;
    this.data = {};

    this.fetch = function(url) {
        //return promise 
        return (
            $http.get(url).then (function onFulfilled(response) {
                //Won't work
                //this.data = response.data;

                //Instead use the binding
                myService.data = response.data;
                //Return data for chaining
                return myService.data;
            }).catch (function onRejected(response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                //throw to chain rejection
                throw response;
            });
        );
    };
});
```

The `this` context in the `onFulfilled` function is not the same as the `this` context of the service. Instead bind the `this` context of the service to a variable and use that variable in the `onFulfilled` function of the promise `.then` method.

Also be aware that `this.data` variable of the service gets set **in the future** sometime after the XHR by the `$http` service completes. To be sure the data is available, use the promise that the `fetch` function returns.

### In the controller

```
var promise = myService.fetch(url);

promise.then (function onFulfilled(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).catch( function onRejected(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse.status);
});
```