# Using factory/service for pushing data in array between controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

new to AngularJS and trying to figure out how to pushing an array of objects data (not input strings) between controllers. Currently, my code pushes data into one controller('ChooseTabCtrl') but I want to push to another controller ('ListTabCtrl') so that the list displays on another page. I'm confused b/c most examples show only when a user enters a string of text. My project adds a fave by clicking a button. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a service and then inject it in both controllers. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js) is what you are looking for. Answer marked as accepted also gives a pretty nice example. Hope this helped.