# service provider is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what i need

- i need to pass values selected from one controller to another
- i have reffer link : [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

js code

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.service('productService', function() {
   var productList = [];

   var addProduct = function(newObj) {
     productList.push(newObj);
   };

   var getProducts = function(){
    return productList;
   };

   return {
     addProduct: addProduct,
     getProducts: getProducts
   };
 });




app.controller('parentController', function ($scope,productService) {
  $scope.change = function () {
    alert($scope.value);
  }
});
```

error

```
error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productServiceProvider <- productService <- parentController
```

- i need to pass data from controller to another .
- whereas i don"t understand why its producing such errors.

Comment: you define `app` after your first `app.service`. Are they in different modules/files?

Comment: I guess the fact that `app` is used before it is created is a typo... In any case, `module.service` has to return a *constructor*; try `module.factory` if you want to return the instance of the service.

Comment: your code is working fine. make sure you have included your service file in your project also check the order of deceleration of `module` and `service`.

Comment: no its not working service is not right option , brodcast would be good

Comment: There is nothing wrong in provided code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/)

Comment: May be you fix a service name typo, while copy code to your question.

Comment: I add this kind of typo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/1/) and get same error. Just check your actual service name.

Comment: @user2818060 if service is not right choice then why are you using it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This error results from the `$injector` being unable to resolve a required dependency.
To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

I have two guess for this:

- You fix a service name typo, while copy code to your question [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/1/).
  Just check your actual service name
- You redeclare `angular.module` [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/2/)

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('productService', function() {
  return {};
});

app = angular.module('myApp', []); // <- module redeclared
app.controller('parentController', function ($scope,productService) {
  $scope.value = 'World'
});
```

`angular.module('myApp', [])` creates new instance of module without knowing previous declared providers.
You can retrieve it for subsequent use with `angular.module('myApp')`.

Comment: i cannot add  drop down values in addproduct() function  :undefined

Comment: vp_arth you have explain in html i need to pass value in another controller :ie i m making http request so i need to pass value in api: https://jsfiddle.net/wwvgfcp3/7/

Comment: Just inject your service to that controller and call `productService.getProducts()` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/9/). This all is unrelated to `unknown provider` error. Explain please, what it was? Redeclaring? Typo?

Comment: in console.log it still [] empty array i don"t need to display in html i need to pass value in http://link?id=+value

Comment: it's because controller code is running while application initialization only, you have empty array here. You can use `$scope.products` or even call `getProducts()` again everywhere you need.

Comment: Please start new question if you want to ask something else :)

Comment: can you give some code snippet with respect in communication within controller : jsfiddle

Comment: ok, there is sub-pub snippet: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/wwvgfcp3/11/). Controller subcribes for changes, and receives changed list any time new product added.

Answer (score -1):

you have declared service before module declearation. so it is not added to your module

follow these steps

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

then create controllers and service

```
app.service('productService', function() { ....
```

and

```
app.controller('parentController', function ($scope,productService) {...
```

I have change your fiddle example check [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wwvgfcp3/8/),

I have created another controller which share same service.

Comment: jetndr it was just typing code issue i have declare like this manner only

Comment: i think service is not right choice to deal communication

Comment: yes, you can use a parent controller to share this data or event based solution.

Comment: after this step app.controller('parentController', function ($scope,productService) {... error occurs

Comment: could you plz create a demo on plunker, so that we can resolve it easily