# How to Build Communication between two controllers in components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If it possible, I want call some function in one controller which will load data to another component's controller.

Comment: use services for this

Comment: Or you can use controller aliases `ng-controller="ctrlNameA as ctrlA"` then you can do `ng-click="ctrlA.myFunction(ctrlB.something)"` if you need both controllers in the same view if not use service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to establish communication between controllers, it just depends on the level of abstraction you want in your application. Please have a look at these posts to get more idea about this: [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers), 
[Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js), 
[Using services and messages to share data between controllers in AngularJs](https://objectpartners.com/2013/08/21/using-services-and-messages-to-share-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs/)

Comment: Ok, is it suitable for components?