# Angular: How do I pass data between 2 views of a single page app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first attempt at Angular.js. I am attempting to create a single page app which load some JSON and displays a list. When I click a link in the list it should go to a new page and populate the page in greater detail via the id from the JSON data.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Here is the JavaScript (easyjet.js):

```
    var app = angular.module('easyjet', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('flights', {
        url: '/', 
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
        controller: 'ResultsController'
    })
    .state('details', {
        url: '/detail/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/fulldetails.html',
        controller: 'ResultsController'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});


app.controller('ResultsController', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

    console.log($stateParams); 

    // Get JSON data
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://ejtestbed.herokuapp.com/flights"
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.resultsData = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.resultsData = response.statusText;
        console.log("Oops! Couldn't load JSON!");
    });

    // Select and display result details
    $scope.selectedResult = null;

    $scope.selectResult = function (result) {
        $scope.selectedResult = result;
    };

    //Sorting default setting
    $scope.order = "flightNumber.number";

});
```

Here is the default HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="easyjet">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Easyjet, Flights</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="easyjet.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The template files:
1. list.html

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Filtering & Sorting -->
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Search anything..." />
        <select ng-model="order">
            <option value="flightNumber.number">Flight Number (ASC)</option>
            <option value="-flightNumber.number">Flight Number (DEC)</option>
            <option value="localDepartureTime">Date (ASC)</option>
            <option value="-localDepartureTime">Date (DEC)</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Result List -->
    <div class="result" 
        ng-repeat="result in filteredResults = (resultsData | filter: search | orderBy: order)" 
        ng-style="{ 'background-color': result.id == selectedResult.id ? 'lightgray' : '' }"
        ng-click="selectResult(result)">

        <span style="display:none;">{{ $index }}</span>
        <a ng-href="#/detail/{{ result.id }}"><span>EZY {{ result.flightNumber.number }}</span></a>
        <span>From: {{ result.departureAirport }}</span> 
        <span>To: {{ result.arrivalAirport }}</span>
        <span>Date: {{ result.localDepartureTime | date:"longDate" }}</span>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="filteredResults.length == 0">No Result Found</div>

</div>
```

2. fulldetails.html

- Flight Number: {{ selectedResult.flightNumber.carrierCode }} {{ selectedResult.flightNumber.number }}
- From: {{ selectedResult.departureAirport }}
- To: {{ selectedResult.arrivalAirport }}
- Departure Terminal: {{ selectedResult.depTerminalName }}
- Departure Time: {{ selectedResult.localDepartureTime | date:"longDate" }}
- Arrival Time: {{ selectedResult.localArrivalTime | date:"longDate" }}
- Seats Available: {{ selectedResult.seatsAvailable }}
- Adult Fare: {{ selectedResult.prices.adult.value }}
- Debit Card Booking Fee: {{ selectedResult.prices.adult.valueWithDebitCard }}
- Credit Card Booking Fee: {{ selectedResult.prices.adult.valueWithCreditCard }}
- Child Fare: {{ selectedResult.prices.child.value }}
- Debit Card Booking Fee: {{ selectedResult.prices.child.valueWithDebitCard }}
- Credit Card Booking Fee: {{ selectedResult.prices.child.valueWithCreditCard }}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: i don't think so it seems he's using same controller and want to share data between two different views only not Controller. i'm right @Nasir

Comment: @Manish: Using a service seems to be a good approach.

Comment: @Jorawar Singh: That would be the ideal solution because this app is really simple. Yes your'e right

Comment: then just go with that i can send you an example if you want using cache :-) and don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: Okay that'd be great. Will accept, thanks

Comment: updated my answer with simple example :-)

Comment: @Nasir Yes using  service is always a better choice when it comes to sharing data between two views or controllers.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a service which will do the call and store the data between the pages.

Your controllers will call this service to get the data or ask to refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are Using same controller then you can store your data in cache or local-storage other wise if you use service to store data and same controller it will break because service will also be reloaded and loose the data if you are not using same controller then you should definitely use service as best practice**

How to work with cache? use $cacheFactory in controller

check on controller loaded

```
 var yourCache = $cacheFactory.get('yourCache') || $cacheFactory('searchCache');
```

in your function after success just save to cache

```
yourCache.put(key, value);
```

and for removing it

```
yourCache.remove('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular service to share the `variable` with two ore more `controllers`

But here your problem is to share the values between **views that having same controller**.

Here when ever you are changing the view, the `controller` **reloads**. So you have to store that value in local storage or session storage (even though we can setup a service, better option is localStorage or sessionStorage).

For this you can use `$localStorage` or `$sessionStorage` dependencies.