# Passing data to the modal window. Angular js

Tags: angularjs

So I've got a json file from which I outputed the list of contacts in the table. Each row has a button to click on to proceed to the modal window with that particular row you've clicked on. I handled the window but I can't figure out how do I pass that data to the modal window.

Comment: Is your modal built using a directive?

Comment: I recommend this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap UI, you can add it as a `resolve` entry:

```
yourItems = [...];

$uibModal.open({
  ...
  controller: 'MyModalCtrl as modal',
  resolve: {
    modalItems: function() {
      return yourItems;
    }
  }
})
```

And inject it into your controller like so:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyModalCtrl', function(yourItems) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you're project is set up, but there are two libraries that I recommend for creating modals easily.

[ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) and [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Both of these have simple methods for attaching data and controllers to dialogs as well as creating your own templates and styles for them.