# How to pass data to other controller in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers, I want to have next thing:
when I click on item in controllerOne it should highlight element with the same ID in controllerTwo.
I have highlighting method  But how to send event with ID from controllerOne to controllerTwo ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

Keep the shared data in a service that's accessible from both controllers, see https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#defer-controller-logic-to-services

Answer (score 0):

Use [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) to pass variables in the URL:

```
/controller2route/:action/:id
```

for example:

```
/details/highlight/2
```

You can then use ifs and switches to call the appropriate function, for example highlight(2) for the above URL.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Answer (score 0):

You can you route parameter in routing.

In routing

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/users/:userId", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm",
        controller:"controllerTwo "
    })
})
```

and in controllerTwo use $routeParams to get the user id.

```
app.controller('controllerTwo',function($scope,$routeParams){
  var userId = $routeParams.userId;
})
```

and the one better solution is to use services. Here is the link 
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services