# how to pass response data one controller to another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Pass response data one controller to another controller using  api call (like as user register to use (UserController) a the time of save data using (POST method)  the into data base after getting response that response to pass to  another controller).

Comment: It would help us give you an answer if you posted some code relating to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)