# how to passing data from one controller to another controller using angular js 1

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

hi all i using angular js i need to transfer the value from one page controller to another page controller and get that value into an a scope anybody help how to do this

## code Page1.html

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "angularUtils.directives.dirPagination", "ngNotify", "ngCookies","ngRoute"]);
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter','$notify','$cookieStore',
 function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $notify, $cookieStore)
 {
   $scope.Message="Hi welcome"

 }]);
```

## now i want to show scope message into page2 controller

```
 var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "angularUtils.directives.dirPagination", "ngNotify", "ngCookies","ngRoute"]);
    app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter','$notify','$cookieStore',
     function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $notify, $cookieStore)
     {
       ///here i want get that scope value

     }]);
```

Comment: easy solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: See the marked duplicate, its spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use services for it .
Services

```
   app.factory('myService', function() {
 var message= [];
 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }
 function set(mes) {
   message.push(mes)
 }
 function get() {
  return message;
 }



});
```

And in ctrl

ctrl1

```
$scope.message1= 'Hi';
  myService.set($scope.message1);
```

ctrl2

```
var message =  myService.get()
```

Comment: cookie will not reflect imediately once page refresh then only it's work

Comment: i have one dropdown in page 1 when i select the value mens reflects the page2 controller

Comment: You should use $watch for it . But best practice is use services or factory

Comment: i have confused give some fiddle or sample code yar

Comment: I dont have a dropdown or routing now . Can you create plnkr or fiddle ?

Comment: it's little tricky i am not able to create fiddle @thanh tung

Comment: i have header page that include in main page using ng-include in header have a dropdown when i change that content page content will change

Comment: @jose here is plnkr i create . check this http://plnkr.co/edit/jfoDRcOSl0hP8ErVlZ3u?p=preview

Comment: i have both controller have an indivudal page @Thsnh Tung

Comment: myService.set($scope.message1); is not create i think  when i check it console it's undefined

Comment: Are your check the plnkn ? . First go page 1 , type input and hit button click , then go page 2 and see it http://plnkr.co/edit/jfoDRcOSl0hP8ErVlZ3u?p=preview

Comment: plunker working fine yar thanks but i have controller in different page it's not working yar so only i ask otherwise wait i will update my code

Comment: if you inject services as dependency, you can use it anywhere . But i will wait you update your code

Comment: Kindly check @ Thanh Tùng
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694605/how-to-switch-controller-values-from-ng-include-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`:

```
// do not forget to inject $rootScope as dependency
$rootScope.Message="Hi welcome";
```

But the best practice is using a `service` and share data and use it in any controller you want.

Comment: yes i need service give sample @vahid najafi or please elabrate the root scope

Comment: About `$rootScope`, when you created it as mentioned in the answer, you can access it like `$scope`. And for `service` take a look at here https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/services-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

You should define a service and write getter/setter functions on this.

```
angular.module('app').service('msgService', function () {
  var message;
  this.setMsg = function (msg) {
     message = msg;
  };

  this.getMsg = function () {
     return message;
  };
});
```

Now you should use the `setMeg` function in `Controller1` and `getMsg` function in `Controller2` after injecting the dependency like this.

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter','$notify','$cookieStore', 'msgService',
   function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $notify, $cookieStore, msgService)
   {
     $scope.Message="Hi welcome"
     msgService.setMsg($scope.Message);
   }]);


app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter','$notify','$cookieStore', 'msgService',
 function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $notify, $cookieStore, msgService)
 {
   ///here i want get that scope value
   console.log('message from contoller 1 is : ', msgService.getMsg());
 }]);
```

Comment: i get an a error look like this
Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: i get undefined yr

Comment: you probably forgot to add `msgService` in the controllers dependancies list. see at the end of the above solution.You also need to add the service file in your _index.html_.

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing data from one controller to another using service**

We can create a service to `set` and `get` the data between the `controllers` and then inject that service in the controller function where we want to use it.

**Service :**

```
app.service('setGetData', function() {
  var data = '';
    getData: function() { return data; },
    setData: function(requestData) { data = requestData; }
});
```

**Controllers :**

app.controller('Controller1', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

// To set the data from the one controller
  $scope.Message="Hi welcome";
  setGetData.setData($scope.Message);

}]);

```
app.controller('Controller2', ['setGetData',function(setGetData) {

  // To get the data from the another controller  
  var res = setGetData.getData();
  console.log(res); // Hi welcome

}]);
```

Here, we can see that `Controller1` is used for setting the data and `Controller2` is used for getting the data. So, we can share the data from one controller to another controller like this.