# Angularjs: passing arguments between controllers

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to pass arguments between controllers in Angularjs? I am using the $rootscope to broadcast arguments but it doesn't seem to be the most efficient.

Comment: you can also use service which is a singleton in angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to share data between controllers is with a Service.

It's described well in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181543/2503944

That answer uses a service to share products between controllers. You can apply that to whatever you need to share between yours.