# How do I pass the variable in a function into my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass the videoUrl variable in the showResponse function into my controller.  I've been trying to figure out a solution without success. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}])

// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    var videoUrl = [];
    for (prop in response.items) {
        videoUrl[prop] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + response.items[prop].snippet.resourceId.videoId;    
    }
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('#######');
    search();
}

function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        playlistId: '########'
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variables to AngularJS controller, best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703477/pass-variables-to-angularjs-controller-best-practice)

Comment: Where are you trying to call "showResponse" from?

Comment: I'm using the google apis client library, but I guess you can't use it with angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably better/easier if you could get this stuff *into* angular, so that it's all happening within services. That's how data sharing is supposed to happen in angular. But maybe that's challenging due to the nature of `onClientLoad`. The dirty way to do it is:

Get the controller's scope directly and set it on that scope. Assuming you've got something defined like:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl"></div>
```

you can get that controller's scope using jQuery:

```
function showResponse(response) {
  var videoUrl = [];
  for (prop in response.items) {
    videoUrl[prop] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + response.items[prop].snippet.resourceId.videoId;    
  }
  var scope = $('[ng-controller="mainCtrl"]').scope();
  scope.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}
```

Note that this will cause angular purists to weep and gnash their teeth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wanted to utilize the existing google api client library, but I guess I will try to do it the angular way.